# Test case specifically constructed to make algorithm fail

Tags: testing, naming

This is a question on nomenclature. In complexity theory of algorithms, there is a name for a test case constructed specifically to make the algorithm fail. I had that word in my head, but can't recall it for the life of me now. I'm hoping someone here can help. What is the word for an input that is incredibly unlikely to occur in the real world but someone who knows the algorithm can construct to make it fail or perform badly?

Answer (score 1):

You may be thinking of an [adversary](https://jeffe.cs.illinois.edu/teaching/algorithms/notes/13-adversary.pdf):

> The idea is that an all-powerful malicious adversary pretends to choose an input for the algorithm. When the algorithm wants looks at a bit, the adversary sets that bit to whatever value will make the algorithm do the most work.

Comment: Thanks, but not quite. It was a word starting with d, I think. It was a property of the test case itself, not one who constructed it.

Comment: I think my university lecturer might have called it an "oracle" or a "daemon", but googling those didn't turn up any relevant results.

Comment: Oh, a property of the test case itself. I don't know what that would be, but I'm curious to find out!

Comment: The word I was looking for was "pathological case".

Answer (score 1):

The word I was looking for was "pathological case". When reading about the Cauchy distribution (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cauchy_distribution), I chanced upon it again seeing it described as a "pathological distribution".